# SIGCHI Extended Abstract - make image extend through margin and into text

Tags: marginpar

Using the SIGCHI Extended Abstract template, does anyone have an example that will make an image go across entire page -- including the margin area. Or maybe the margin plus the left column?   Essentially I need any way to utilize that space other than vertically.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! From your description (limiting the amount of vertical space used) I'm guessing that you have a page limit and you want to submit the abstract somewhere. In that case you are probably not allowed to have images in the margin, because most conferences and journals want their submissions to be consistently formatted with the margins respected.

Comment: Hi Marijn, Thanks for the reply!  Yes, it is for a conference paper.  The CHI case studies use a special template called an Extended Abstract that is landscape with a left-hand margin (8 page max).  The template allows/encourages the use of the margin for notes and images.  But I do visualization and have wide rather than narrow images.  Ah well, I was hoping someone who submitted to CHI may have solved this already.  Take care.

Comment: If you can make a small example document and post it here it will probably help in getting an answer. Just one page with some text and a wide image. In your example you can use `\includegraphics[width=290mm]{example-image}` as a wide image, this is a pre-installed dummy image that is always available. For filler text you can use the `lipsum` package. Also include a link to the template.